# pytest / django: multiple fixtures, multiple assertions, asserting expectations

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a working, valid test for a django project, `dummy_book` and `test_profile` are both fixtures. Notice it has two assertions:

```py
def test_correct_items_in_feed(client, dummy_book, test_profile):
    some_author = dummy_book.author_set.first()
    # profile subscribes to author
    Subscription.attempt_addition_by_id(test_profile, some_author.vendor_id)
    client.login(username=test_profile.user.username, password="somepassword")
    test_profile.save()
    # wants fiction books, feed requested
    requested_url = reverse("personal_feed", args=[test_profile.auth_token])
    resp = client.get(requested_url, follow=True)
    assert dummy_book.title in str(resp.content)
    # user no longer wants fiction books, feed requested
    test_profile.notify_fiction = False
    test_profile.save()
    resp = client.get(f"/users/feeds/{test_profile.auth_token}", follow=True)
    assert dummy_book.title not in str(resp.content)
```

What I'm looking to implement now is a way to test two different `test_profile`s:

1. one `test_premium_profile` which is allowed to filter `Book`s by type (notice the model attribute `test_profile.notify_fiction`)
2. Another `test_free_profile` which is NOT allowed to filter `Book`s by type

I already have the logic for the above, which simply ignores `test_free_profile`'s preferences regarding this atrribute.

The challenge here comes from the fact that for these two different profiles, we need to assert different assertions. Specifically, for `test_free_profile` `dummy_book.title` should be in the `resp.content` in both scenarios, while for `test_premium_profile` it should only be there in the first scenario.

How can I arrange these different assertions for both kinds of `Profile`s, without duplicating this test and the code in it?

I know one easier solution is to split this test into two, but I'm not interested in that and for the sake of education that is out of the question.

Comment: Take a closer look at test parametrizing: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

Comment: @4140tm I already have, the question is written after having gone over that.

Comment: When I was using pytest I also wondered the same thing, lets say I have an`addition` function, how do I specify the expected result through fixtures? via parametrized? There is no documentation about what canonical way to do it.